# Updating Multiple Rows using .edit in vba access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

I hope I can ask this right.
I have a listbox on a form (access 2007) and have it set on "simple" so I can multi-select.
I am trying to update multiple columns in a table, based on the selections in the listbox. I have a few textboxes that I want to use as the information to update the table. 
I have a loop that is only updating the first record in the table no matter how many items are selected. 
I think I understand why it's only updating the first record from my loop but am not sure

```
Dim db  As DAO.Database
Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenDynaset)

Dim i As Variant

    For Each i In Listbox.ItemsSelected

    With rs
    .Edit

     !Col1 = Me.Textbox1
     !Col2 = Me.Textbox2
     !Col3 = Me.Textbox3

    .Update

    End With
    Next
```

I assume this is because I am not specifying the "where" in the loop I want my table updated, but I have no idea how to do this in this loop. I would have 3 columns in the listbox (at positions 1, 3 and 4) that all need to be included to specify which records in the table need to be updated. I have tried this as well using an sql query with DoCmd.RunSql but it seems impossible to change the focus of the ListIndex mid-query. Aplogies for my lack of knowledge I am pretty new to visual basic. **Please Help**

Comment: I would but I totally don't understand what is the use of the textboxes. Aren't the multicolumn listbox selections what you want to update in the table? And as I understand, you don't need .edit / .update, but the execution of INSERT or UPDATE SQL Statements...

Comment: Hiya Kim, I am using the listbox to select which rows in the table I need to change. I am using the textboxes to put information in the columns of those rows. The problem I am having is that I have 3 columns in the listbox which indicate which records need to be changed in the table, and I can't seem to change the focus of the listindex mid-query which is why i thought it easier to use .edit/.update. Thanks for replying :-)

Comment: So it's the same (textbox) information for each of the rows you selected?

Comment: Hi TheRedOne, you can use the code button `{}` to format code.

Comment: Yep, basically I'm updating a training database with a date, Trainer, Comments... stuff like that. I want to be able to select multiple people and add the same info for all of them..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified example how I would give it a try if I understood correctly:

```
Sub MultiSelect_Listbox()

Dim lCnt as Long
dim lID as long     
dim sSQL_Update as string    

dim sText_1 as String
dim sText_2 as String
dim sText_3 as String

dim bSuccess as Boolean

sText_1 = me.txt_Textbox_1
sText_2 = me.txt_Textbox_2
sText_3 = me.txt_Textbox_3    

With Me.lst_Listbox
    For lCnt = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(lCnt) Then
            lID = .Column(0, lCnt - 1)
            'Example update for 1 column
            sSQL_Update = "UPDATE T_TABLE SET COL_TEXT_1 = '" & sText_1 & "' WHERE ID = " & lID & ";"
            bSuccess = Update_Statement(sSQL_Update)
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub

Public Function Update_Statement(sUpdate_Stmt) As Boolean

Dim db                          As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute (sUpdate_Stmt)
Update_Statement = True

End Function
```

Comment: I am going to try and make use of this Kim thanks. Will take me a bit to fully understand it. Just to explain. I pick e.g 3 rows from my list box. I enter the text, and tick checkboxes etc.. which i have created in the form. Then I click a button and the text, checkbox info etc.. updates the relevant rows in my table. Coulmns 1,3 and 4 in the listbox are the combined keys for which I need to update my table. It's working but it only updates the first row in the table and not the three that I've picked. Your post has given me much to think about :)

Comment: btw thanks remou, I didn't realise what you meant but I see yuo've fixed it for me ;-)

Comment: Hi Kim, no joy, I'm getting an error saying that the update statement is ambiguous, sorry if I am not understanding it all properly :-/

Comment: You need to modify table / field names and variables according to your needs... would that help?

Comment: I did all that Kim yes, the only variables I didn't change were "bSuccess = Update_Statement(sSQL_Update)
", "Update_Statement(sUpdate_Stmt)", "db.Execute (sUpdate_Stmt) and
Update_Statement = True . Apologies, I left work yesterday around the time you replied. I am thinking now that if I change the focus on the listbox and save those variables, then use them in the sql statement that may work. Here's hoping..! :-)
"

Comment: Yep, you better put the values selected in the variable (like in the example); due to the loop, the variable can be overwritten/reused each time.

Comment: Hi Kim, just to let you know I finally got it to work. I needed to change the indexes in the listbox by using the .Column like you have in your example above. Thank you so much for taking the time to give a hand and stop an Irish bloke from meltdown :-)... Red

Comment: No problem :-) Indeed, take care that the Column(x, y) has to start at Column(0,0).